# Building a complex Map with Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to build a `Map` with nested map inside with the help of java 8 API.

I have a `List<Person> persons`. Each person has a `String personId` and owns a `List<Children> children`

Each child has a `String childId` and a `List<String> hobbies`.

I want to build : `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>> hobbies`

My key in the outer map is `personId`.

My key in the inner map is `childId` and the associated value is the `List<String> hobbies` for this specific child.

Any idea ? Is it possible ?

Without java 8 :

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>> hobbies = new HashMap<>();
persons.forEach(person -> { 
    String personId = person.getPersonId(); 
    Map<String, List<String>> hobbiesByPerson = hobbies.get(personId); 
    if (hobbiesByPerson == null) { 
        hobbiesByPerson = new HashMap<>(); hobbies.put(personId, hobbiesByPerson ); 
    } 
    for (Child child: person.getChildren()) { 
        hobbiesByPerson.put(person.getPersonId(), child.getHobbies()); 
    }
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Without java 8 :             Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>> hobbies = new HashMap<>();
            persons.forEach(person -> {
             String personId = person.getPersonId();
             Map<String, List<String>> hobbiesByPerson = hobbies.get(personId);
             if (hobbiesByPerson == null) {
              hobbiesByPerson = new HashMap<>();
              hobbies.put(personId, hobbiesByPerson );
             }
             for (Child child: person.getChildren()) {
              hobbiesByPerson.put(person.getPersonId(), child.getHobbies());
   
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>> hobbies =
    persons.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person:getPersonId,
                                     p -> p.getChildren()
                                           .stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Child::getChildId,
                                                                     Child::getHobbies))));
```

You stream over the `List`, and collect the elements into a `Map`, where the key in a personId and the value is a `Map` that you build by streaming over the children.